# Spring MVC + Hibernate + Session Factory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mvc

Следующий вопроc.
Есть Spring MVC приложение - круд, есть сервис, есть дао.
В Дао мы получаем SessionFactory из конфига.
Имет ли смысл заводить в дао сессию и открывать - закрывать её

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    // заменить на Entity Manager
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session;
    @Autowired
    private UserDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.save(user);
        session.close();
    }
```

Или эта операция излишняя и можно делать так

```
@Override
public void addUser(User user) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
}
```

В чем принципиальная разница и как будет правильнее?

Answer (score 1):

а почему не использовать спринговые репозитории? тогда не надо будет свое DAO. Если операции стандартные, то это будет правильнее.

Если нужно будет как-то кастомизировать, то написать реализацию интерфейса и заинжектить туда EntityManager, а Спринг сам все разрулит.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories

Comment: Согласен! Репозитории по-факту - это и есть DAO слой приложения, просто реализованный через Spring.